# VSCODE Complete existing word in de file

Tags: visual-studio-code

In gedit there is a plugin that completes an existing word in the same file and in different files if both are open.

Does VSCODE have any similar extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, VSCode has auto-complete.  Language extensions can provide customized auto-complete capabilities, such as context filtering, implicit vocabularies, etc.  However, the level of capability will depend on which extensions you have installed and are active.  If none of the active extensions provide auto-complete, then VSCode itself provides a very basic version automatically, which is limited to suggesting "words" that have already been entered in the current document.

Comment: It is possible to run both simultaneously? That is, the auto-complete of the extension and the vscode auto-complete standard.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Not that I know of.  From my own experience writing extensions, once the extension provides auto-complete suggestions, that's all the user will see.